# In firefox browser, Window.open strangely displaying [object Window] after clicking

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, browser, window.open

I have set anchor link so that on click it will open link into new window.

I have used below code to open new link into new window.

`<a href="javascript:window.open('https://www.remax.fi/fi/kiinteistonvalitys/tietosuojaseloste/', 'newwindow', 'fullscreen=1')">"tietosuojaselosteeseen"</a>`

url : `https://www.remax.fi/fi/`

On above url page, in bottom there been contact form on which I have set anchor link in text `tietosuojaselosteeseen`.

In chrome browser it working properly but In firefox browser it display error page which show `[object Window]` text.

Please find screenshot for further clarification.

I have tried much to find solution of this problem but not able to figure out this.

Please help me if any one have idea regarding it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: So when you click your link, it opens a page in chrome but firefox the page that opens has an error? Also, Please share relevant code.

Comment: @TusharShahi yes in chrome browser it working fine, poblem only in firefox browser. even I have tried to open it in incognito mode of firefix browser also but same error. There has not been any other relevant code just it is just anchor link with window.open method.

Comment: So instead of "tietosuojaselosteeseen" your anchor becomes Object.window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just use onlick event for this. You can modify your code like this

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.open('https://www.remax.fi/fi/kiinteistonvalitys/tietosuojaseloste/', 'newwindow', 'fullscreen=1');return false;">"tietosuojaselosteeseen"</a>
```

Here, on href it will execute like javascript:void(0); and we call the window.open on click event. Also return false if there are other events triggers with it.

Answer (score 4):

When you put the Javascript in the href, the page also navigates to whatever the Javascript returns. In this case window.open returns a copy of the window object, which can't be navigated to.

You can solve this by moving the Javascript to onclick and having a `href="#"`, or you can add a `;return false` after the window.open, or put `void()` around the window.open,

Comment: Actually [specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#javascript-protocol) ask that the response is used only for string return values ("*If Type(result) is String*"). Firefox behavior is incorrect here.